# Question from Stewart's Calculus regarding proof of independence of path and conservative vector fields.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, vector-analysis, fake-proofs

> Please look over this proof.  In the proof, it says: "Notice that the first of these integrals does not depend on $x$, so..."
>
> How is that so? $C_1$ does depend on $x$.  How/Why does it not depend on $x$?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first integral is $f(x_1,y)$ as defined in the second line of the proof, which is only a function of $y$ with $x = x_1$ fixed.

Comment: But we can see that if we travel on $C_1$ we go to from $(a,b) \rightarrow (x_1,y)$.  So $x_1-a \neq 0$

Comment: The value of the integral depends on what $x_1$ is, but the value itself is fixed: the integral is now a function of $y$ only.